# Android build failed due to plugin error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed the plugin `com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob` a while ago, but I removed the plugin last month. I just deleted the plugin folder to delete the plugin. When I try to build the project I do get an error.

These are the things I have tried:

Remove the plugin on this way: `cordova plugin rm com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob`. Delete the `com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob` plugin in the `fetch.xml` and the `android.xml` files in the plugins folder.

This is the error I do get when i'm typing in: `cordova build android`:

```
   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Dirk\Hollan d App 2015\Ionic\Holland\plugins\com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob\plugin.xml' at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18) at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15) at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roam ing\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\util\xml-helpers.js:11 8:27) at new PluginInfo (C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova \node_modules\cordova-lib\src\PluginInfo.js:298:37) at PluginInfoProvider.get (C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules \cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\PluginInfoProvider.js:35:32) at C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co rdova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:79:45 at Array.forEach (native) at Object.handlePrepare (C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\prepare.js:77:24) at C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co rdova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:108:21 at Array.map (native)
```

I hope that anyone have had the same problem or know a way to resolve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to remove a plugin would be:

```
cordova plugin rm com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.admob
```

You should not have to delete anything manually. Maybe you can correct all XML files now by deleting the platform and add it again, like so:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

After these command you can rebuild the project for Android, like so:

```
cordova build android
```

Also note if you are using Ionic as the tag to the questions suggest, you can replace `cordova` with `ionic` in all commands.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please click the checkmark next to the answer to accept the answer.

Comment: I worked, but i manually had to remove plugins before add platform.